# How could I add column and row percentages to a crosstab in R (like in an excel Pivot Table)?

Tags: r, crosstab

I have the following code:

```
alldata2019_v2 %>% tabyl(agerange,gender) %>% 
                adorn_totals(c("row","col")) %>% 
                mutate_if(is.numeric, format, big.mark = ",")
```

And it provides the expected table:

| agerange | Female | Male | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 or less | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 18 to 24 | 41,486 | 84,444 | 125,930 |
| 25 to 29 | 239,969 | 543,021 | 782,990 |
| 30 to 34 | 245,211 | 604,262 | 849,473 |
| 35 to 39 | 120,084 | 397,880 | 517,964 |
| 40 to 44 | 63,102 | 235,768 | 298,870 |
| 45 to 49 | 38,889 | 154,196 | 193,085 |
| 50 to 54 | 36,612 | 134,244 | 170,856 |
| 55 to 59 | 36,810 | 115,891 | 152,701 |
| 60 or more | 35,690 | 130,044 | 165,734 |
| Total | 857,858 | 2,399,750 | 3,257,608 |

The problem is I cant find a way to add a columns for percentages by row and by column. Is there a way to do it?

| agerange | Female | Male | Total | Female_pct | Male_pct | Age_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 or less | 5 | 0 | 5 | 100% | 0% | 0% |
| 18 to 24 | 41,486 | 84,444 | 125,930 | 33% | 67% | 4% |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

the input data has this strcture:

| gender | usertype | agerange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Subscriber | 30 to 34 |
| Female | Subscriber | 30 to 34 |
| Female | Subscriber | 25 to 29 |
| Male | Subscriber | 25 to 29 |
| Male | Subscriber | 25 to 29 |
| Female | Subscriber | 35 to 39 |

Comment: What packages are you working with? `janitor`?

Comment: I tried it but unfourtunately did not work

Comment: @camille tidyverse, lubridate, janitor, data.table and knitr

Comment: @DanielSossa You can check the code in the solution.  it works fine for me (also showed a reproducible example with mtcars data)

Comment: The output from `adorn_percentages` needs to be multiplied by 100 and pasted with `%` if you need that format as in your expected

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(stringr)
out %>%
    mutate(across(-1, readr::parse_number)) %>% 
   adorn_percentages() %>%
   select(-agerange) %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_c(., 'pct'), everything()) %>%
   bind_cols(out, .)
```

---

Reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>% 
   tabyl(am, cyl) %>%
    magrittr::multiply_by(1000) %>%
    adorn_totals(c("row", "col")) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
      ~ formattable::comma(., digits = 2, big.mark = ","))) -> out

out %>% 
   adorn_percentages() %>% 
   select(-am, -Total) %>%
   rename_with(~ str_c(., 'pct'), everything()) %>%   
    bind_cols(out, .)
    am         4        6         8     Total 4pct 6pct 8pct
     0  3,000.00 4,000.00 12,000.00 19,000.00 0.16 0.21 0.63
  1000  8,000.00 3,000.00  2,000.00 13,000.00 0.62 0.23 0.15
 Total 11,000.00 7,000.00 14,000.00 32,000.00 0.34 0.22 0.44
```